# mysql query returns "0 rows inserted"

Tags: mysql

I am trying to upload csv file into mysql database, but 0 row was inserted using the following query. I wonder where should I start looking at the problem

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/Applications/xxx/tmp/student_info.csv" INTO TABLE student_info_table
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(name,age,grade) ;
```

Comment: What does the data in the file look like?

Comment: testname,23,3
testname2,22,3
testname3,22,4

Comment: Are those spaces actually line breaks in the file?

Comment: yes. I copied and pasted in

Comment: the query works on a different table that I just created, but not on the one I need to insert into

Comment: I think I found the problem -- I have a foreign key in the mysql table, and the file I uploaded does not include the foreign information

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is actually in the setup of my database table. It has a foreign key, and in the uploading file, I did not define a valid foreign key value